# Render entity reference field with link in node template

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a content type with an entity reference field to select a user.
Now I would like to render this field in the node template so that the field links to the user profile.
I set the format of the field to "Label" in Manage Display and clicked on the gear so the label is linked to the reference entity.

But because I am printing the field programmatically it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I do in my node template:

```
$field_user = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $item, 'field_user');
$field_user_output = field_view_value('field_collection_item', $item, 'field_user', $field_user[0]);
print render($field_user_output);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This may help with theming field collections, walks through a couple of different ways to accomplish the task: https://www.drupal.org/node/1155752

Answer (score 0):

If the field is configured to display and available on the node, in `node.tpl.php`, you should be able to use:

```
print render($content['field_user']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is the entity reference field is part of some nested field collections. So my field structure looks something like this:

-Field Collection
--Text Field
--Field Collection
---Text Field
---Entity Reference field

I could probably access the field by doing `print render($content['field_first_field_collection']['field_second_field_collection']['field_entity_reference']`, but that seems to be an ugly solution.

Would there be an easier way?